# Summarizing one way, then another for what's left

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Using `iris` as an example. 
After grouping by `Species`, I want to summarize `Sepal.Length` by its `mean`, then summarize all the remaining columns by `last`; (without calling out the remaining columns individually.) Wanting the result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
Species    Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
<fct>             <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa           5.01            3.3          1.4         0.2
2 versicolor       5.94            2.8          4.1         1.3
3 virginica        6.59            3            5.1         1.8
```

This runs without error:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(~last(.))
```

But this doesn't:

```
iris %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length), ~ last(.))
```

I've tried using `everything()` and working with `summarise_at` and `summarise_if`, but I haven't stumbled on the right syntax to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `summarise_at` and `summarise_all` map the same function to selected variables, they can't be used here.

One way to perform different summarisation for different columns in automatic way is to create `expression` using quoting-and-unquoting technique:

```
library(dplyr)

cols = names(iris)[2:4]  # select remaining columns 
col_syms = syms(cols)  # create symbols from strings

summary_vars <- lapply(col_syms, function(col) {
  expr(last(!!col))  # expression that should be evaluated in summarise
})
names(summary_vars) = cols  # new column names (set old names)

iris %>%  
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length), !!!summary_vars)  # open expressions
```

You can see what is going to be evaluated by wrapping dplyr's pipe into `rlang::qq_show()`

Answer (score 1):

does the job, didn't find more elegant :

```
inner_join(iris %>% 
              select(Species,Sepal.Length) %>%
              group_by(Species) %>% 
              summarise_all(list(mean)),
           iris %>% 
              select(-Sepal.Length) %>%
              group_by(Species) %>% 
              summarise_all(list(last)),
           by = "Species")
```